# How to use selective zone(s) while deploying azure vm through terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using the below while deploying a virtual machine to specific zone in region eastus

```
resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "vm" {

  .........
  .........
  zones = [1]
}
```

but terraform validate says
An argument named "zones" is not expected here. Did you mean "zone"?

Comment: Well, there is no argument `zones`, only `zone`: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_virtual_machine#zone

Comment: well, I have see this optional argument in terraform doc . I am trying to find an reference example how I can deploy vm into particular like zone 1 or 2 or 3 . I think do we need to add resource like availability zones or availability sets in terraform files to achieve zones

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should prefer `for_each` and set to count and index. you can use this transformer code to create a virtual Machine in 3 Availability Zone. You can set the number of Zones according to your needs

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "XXXXXXXXX"
  
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "example-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  #count=3
  name                = "example-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "example" {
  #count=3
  name                = "example-machine"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  for_each = local.zones
  zone = each.value
  admin_username      = "adminuser"
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,

  ]
  
  admin_ssh_key {
    username   = "adminuser"
    public_key = file("~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub")
  }

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "Canonical"
    offer     = "UbuntuServer"
    sku       = "16.04-LTS"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}

locals {
  zones = toset(["1","2","3"])
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thankyou Rahul for the answer

I adjusted the zones accordingly for what I require , like below                                                   
                                   
 resource "azurerm_linux_virtual_machine" "jenkins_primary_vm" {
  name                  = "${var.resource_prefix}-jenkins-primary-vm"
  location              = var.location
  size                     = "Standard_DS3_v2"
  zone                   = local.zones["1"]
.......................................................
locals {
  zones = ["1","2","3"]
}

Comment: Technically, `zones = ["1","2","3"]` is a list, which is accessed by indexes (numbers, not strings) starting with 0, not 1. So when you set `zone = local.zones["1"]`, you may actually be assigning your VM to zone 2, because `local.zone["1"]` is converted to `local.zone[1]` which is the second index. The second index has the string value `"2"`. I wanted to post this to prevent confusion by anyone who may try to copy from your comment.